# Terraform create multiple resources using for_each and jsondecode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to create multiple resource(GCP's multiple cloudSQL instances) and this is what I have:

```
locals {
  psql_settings = [
    { "name" : "psql1", "location" : "us-central1", "zone" : "us-central1-c" },
    { "name" : "psql2", "location" : "us-east1", "zone" : "us-east1-b" }
  ]
}
```

I have to use them in json format because this will be stored in consul for dynamic changes.

Using this `locals` value, how I can create multiple resources. I am trying:

```
module "postgresql-db" {
  depends_on = [
    module.vpc
  ]
  source               = "../modules/postgres"
  for_each             = local.psql_settings[0]
  name                 = each.value.name
  random_instance_name = true
  database_version     = "POSTGRES_13"
  project_id           = "xyz-project
  zone                 = each.value.zone
  region               = each.value.location
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
  for_each   = {for idx,val in local.psql_settings: idx => val}
```

The code changes your list of maps, into map of maps, which is required by `for_each`.